# How to see the JavaScript execution process on the site step by step?

Tags: javascript, javascript-debugger

There is a site on which a special key is generated based on the data that is on the source page. Can I somehow "step by step" see the JavaScript code execution process on this site to find where this key is generated? I mean with the ability to track all local / global variables that are created and changed during code execution.

P.S. This key is not stored anywhere, it is generated in the JavaScript code, with this key there is a background connection to the web socket and then this key is not used anywhere else.

Comment: [Use the debugger](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your browser's dev tools. It allows you to set breakpoints and you can see the execution step by step from there.

Follow this tutorial for using it in chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Comment: To add to this, you can trigger a break point in code by adding `debugger;` as one of the lines.