# Zero Array Questions -- Figuring Out How a Solution Works

Tags: javascript, arrays, sequence

https://www.codewars.com/kata/59e270da7997cba3d3000041/javascript

DESCRIPTION:
An array is called zero-plentiful if it contains multiple zeros, and every sequence of zeros is at least 4 items long.

Your task is to return the number of zero sequences if the given array is zero-plentiful, oherwise 0.

Examples
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]  -->  1

1 group of 5 zeros (>= 4), thus the result is 1

[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]  -->  2

2 group of 4 zeros (>= 4), thus the result is 2

[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]  -->  0
1 group of 4 zeros and 1 group of 1 zero (< 4)
*every* sequence of zeros must be at least 4 long, thus the result is 0

[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]  -->  0
1 group of 3 zeros (< 4) and 1 group of 2 zeros (< 4)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  -->  0
no zeros

[]  -->  0
no zeros

```
function zeroPlentiful(arr) {
  let counter = [];
  let index = 0;
  arr.forEach((num, idx) => {
   if (num === 0) {
     counter[index] = counter[index] ? counter[index] + 1 : 1;
   } else {
     index = counter.length;
   } 
  });
  return counter.every(item => item >= 4) ? counter.length : 0;
}
```

Would someone please give me a play-by-play about what's going on in this code?  I've attempted this question a bunch of times and looked at all the solutions, but I'm still having trouble figuring out what's going on.  I understand that the forEach is looking for 0s and non-0 numbers but, beyond that, I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62008816/how-to-see-the-javascript-execution-process-on-the-site-step-by-step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is quite simple actually, the two main variables are `counter` and `index`, counter keeps track of the **number** of zeros in the array. Then, it iterates through the array, and validates if the current position is a zero, and if it is, the `counter` in the position of `index` is incremented.

So for the first array, `[0,0,0,0,0,1]`, the `counter[index]` will be `5`, because there are 5 zeros in sequence, and index was not incremented from it's original value.

And if the value is **not** 0, then it doesn't increment anything on the `counter` but increments `index`, because the sequence of 0s was broken, and now the counter starts on a new position.

Basically it creates an array with the number of zeros in each sequence, then the `return` statement simply runs the [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function, and validates if the sequence was 4 or more.

Comment: Thanks Pedro! That makes more sense